# Is there a way to center an image using Isotope Filter Plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope

So I have this issue (pictures below) of images in portfolio not being in the center when certain width is reached. I'm using bootstrap and so the pictures are in div "col-sm-6 col-md-4". When screen is md, or sm it's perfectly fine and centered(partly, there is still an imperfection when md-4, but it's not that important), yet when it reaches width of exactly 536px it snaps on left and leaves gap on right. What I have found is that this code is responsible for all this nonsense. If i delete this and add css margin: 0 auto on class img-responsive, pictures look as it should, however if I leave Isotope Filter js command issue still persists. Any suggestions?

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    var $container = $('.portfolio-items');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: '*'
    });
    $('.cat a').click(function() {
        $('.cat .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

[Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHroO.png)

[Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqqt5.png)